# What circumstances are concubines allowed these days?

Tags: history, slavery

Concubines used to exist commonly before. Under what circumstances would they be allowed today?

Comment: If there is a war between Muslims and non-Muslims and the Muslims take women from the non-Muslim side as slaves because they are prizes of war (if the Muslims win).